# Changing the mysql default data dir on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I cannot change the default directory for mysql on ubuntu 12.04.

What I tried :

1. service mysql stop
2. I moved /var/lb/mysql /data/mysql
3. datadir = /data/mysql #my.cnf
4. service mysql start

Output :

/var/log/mysql# service mysql start
    start: Job failed to start

When I try and restart:

```
/var/log/mysql# service mysql start
    start: Job failed to start
```

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/137424/moving-mysql-datadir.  It may have something to do with AppArmour

Comment: Did those steps.  Same error.

Comment: All I can suggest is to look in the log files for messages.  After doing a `service mysql start` type `ls -altr /var/log` which will give a list of the latest log files which have been written to in `/var/log`.  Look in each of the recently changed logs for messages.

Answer (score 6):

Bitten by this as well.  At least one problem: [apparmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor).

I fixed it by adding the /data/mysql to /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysql:

...

```
  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
  /data/mysql/ r,
  /data/mysql/** rwk,
```

...

Comment: +1 I am surprised no other post online refers to this fix!